# Git config remote.origin.tagOpt --no-tags has no apparent effect

Tags: git, git-remote, git-config, git-tag

Every time I try to update a particular repository, it fails because the maintainer regularly changes the `nightly` tag:

```
$ git fetch
From https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua
 ! [rejected]        nightly    -> nightly  (would clobber existing tag)
```

I added `remote.origin.tagOpt = --no-tags` to the .git/config. The setting is apparently useless because it fetches the tags regardless.

I also tried `remote.origin.prune = true` and `remote.origin.pruneTags = true` which made no difference.

Here's the full config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    prune = true
    pruneTags = true
    tagOpt = --no-tags
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Here's the relevant part of `man git-fetch`:

> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that you are interested in. This default behavior can be changed by using the --tags or --no-tags options or by configuring remote.<name>.tagOpt. By using a refspec that fetches tags explicitly, you can fetch tags that do not point into branches you are interested in as well.

Is this a git bug or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I discovered a workaround:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = ^refs/tags/*
    tagOpt = --no-tags
```

I'm still wondering if there's a better way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that Git's tag handling always works as claimed in the documentation, and, even with as deep as I've gotten into Git, I'm not always sure what the documentation even *intends* to claim in the first place.  Still, it seems to me that `--no-tags` here should have worked for you.  So I think this is a Git bug—but it's not clearly, definitively a bug: maybe it's supposed to do what it is doing.

That said, what *will* work for you is to tell `git fetch` to forcibly update `refs/tags/nightly` automatically:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/nightly:refs/tags/nightly
```

This will make your Git willing to force-update the `nightly` tag, so that you won't need `--no-tags` to behave.

Obviously your workaround also works.