# Cherry-pick from changes in a branch tracking a remote

Tags: git

I would like to

- Download a repository `https://github.com/somedude/foorepo.git`
- [delete the .git folder inside](https://xkcd.com/1597/), run `git init`
- Create a branch "cherries"
- Code on the main branch

I know how to do the above. How to do the following?

- Set above `foorepo` as remote for the `cherries` branch
- pull commits from `foorepo` and apply them to `cherries`
- `cherry-pick` interesting commits from `cherries` into the main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it: (Some commands can of course also be done via the file manager or in the Git GUI, e.g. Sublime Merge allows adding remotes via menus)

First, I clone the repo, and reinitialize a fresh git repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/someoneelse/theirrepo.git
mv theirrepo mylocalrepo  # I want another name
cd mylocalrepo
rm --recursive --force .git  # delete the .git folder
git init
git add --all
git commit --message 'Fresh start'
```

Next, I create a repo `myexternalrepo` on, for example, [Codeberg](https://codeberg.org).

Then I connect `myexternalrepo/master` to `mylocalrepo/master`:

```
git remote add myexternalrepo https://codeberg.org/me/myexternalrepo.git
git fetch myexternalrepo
git push myexternalrepo master --set-upstream  # '--force' can help. But use only in private repos.
```

`mylocalrepo/master` is now configured, the `pull`/`push` button(s) are functional in the Git GUI.

Now I create `mylocalrepo/cherries` and connect it to `theirrepo/master`:

```
git remote add theirrepo https://github.com/someoneelse/theirrepo.git
git fetch --no-tags theirrepo master  # This time I need just the master and no tags.
git checkout -b cherries theirrepo/master
```

The last thing to do, is to configure, that the pull button of the GUI, when in the `cherries` branch, only fetches the master branch of `theirrepo`, and also ignores the tags. These things make it more difficult to find my own branches and tags. So I make the following changes to the `[remote "theirrepo"]` section in `.git/config`.

To fetch only the master branch, I replace this [refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt):

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/theirrepo/*
```

... with ...

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/theirrepo/master
```

To prevent that the tags are fetched, I add:

```
fetch = ^refs/tags/*
tagOpt = --no-tags
```

The `fetch = ^refs/tags/*` is a negative refspec blocking all tags. It is a workaround for the fact that [setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegttagOpt) `tagOpt = --no-tags` alone seems not to prevent tag fetching, which seems to be a bug in git or in its documentation, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815896/git-config-remote-origin-tagopt-no-tags-has-no-apparent-effect).

Now everything is configured, when on `master`, pulling/pushing will communicate with `myexternalrepo`, and when in `cherries`, pulling will communicate with `theirrepo` (pushing will refuse to work).

Answer (score 1):

> I am searching for the proper git remote add ... command which adds the master branch, and only that, of the remote.

A possible option would be to ["single-branch clone" the original repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309):

```bash
git clone --branch master --single-branch https://github.com/somedude/foorepo.git
cd foorepo
git remote set-url --push origin https://your/own/remote/repository
git switch -c cherries --track origin/master
```

That way, your branch `cherries` can git pull from the original repository master branch, but push to another repository.

Comment: Thank you, I think I found a solution, see my answer. Also, I do not need to push the cherries branch to another repo, just the master branch.

Comment: @NilsLindemann The all idea behind my answer was to avoid getting *all* branches from the initial repository, while keeping an easy way to update your branch with the original repository branch.

Comment: I tested it. It is interesting, but I do not fully understand it. I noticed, it downloads the tags, how to prevent this? And how will I configure it to push/pull my code to/from a specific repo, like in my answer?

Comment: @NilsLindemann By default, it pulls from the repo initially cloned, and push (`git remote set-url --push`) to any repository you want.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that I have read somewhere in the git docs that pulling/pushing to/from a single branch can only be done on the same remote. OK. Meanwhile, I found out how to prevent fetching tags, see my answer.